# For each of the following, determine the constant c so that f(x) satisfies the conditions for being a p.m.f

Tags: probability

For each of the following, determine the constant c so that f(x) satisfies the conditions for being a p.m.f. for a random variable X.

c) f(x) = x/c, x = 1,2,...,n

d) f(x) = c/(x+1)(x+2), x = 0,1,2,3,...

For c I have no idea how to find the answer without knowing the series n(n+1)/2. That is also the answer.
For d I can't figure out how to find the series. 
Please explain. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for $f(x) = x/c$, then $f$ is a p.m.f if the series $\sum_{x=1} ^n \frac{x}{c} = 1$. That is, as $c$ is a constant, 
$$
\sum_{x=1} ^n x = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = c .
$$
In order to calculate $S = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n$, note that 
$$
2S 
= ( 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n ) + ( 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n ) 
= ( 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n ) + ( n + \cdots + 3 + 2 + 1 ) 
$$
which is 
$$
(1 + n) + (2 + n-1) + (3 + n-2) + \cdots + (n + 1)
= n \cdot (n+1)
$$
Hence, $c = \frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$.
For part d, with $f(x) = \frac{c}{(x+1)(x+2)}$, it is almost exactly the same - however, notice that we can sum this as 
$$
f(x) = c \left( \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} \right) .
$$
This should be familiar to you from the partial fraction decomposition approach at least. This should turn into a nicely telescoping series. So,
$$
1 = \sum f(x) = c \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} +- \cdots - \frac{1}{n} \right).
$$
Therefore, $c = \frac{n}{n-1}$.

Comment: You really should not do other people's homework for them. At best, it is morally corrupt. At worst, it is unfair on the student by denying them the very learning process of doing it by themselves, and unfair on the university whose task it is to assess.